# Шаблоны Blade в Laravel 5+

Tags: php, laravel

Есть страница "База" в которой подключаются все скрипты вставляется контент.
Приблизительно имеет вид такой:

```
<head>
    @yield('style')

    @yield('script')
</head>
<body class="sidebar_main_swipe">
<!-- main header -->
<header id="header_main">
    <div class="header_main_content">
        <nav class="uk-navbar">
            @yield('navbar')
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- main header end -->

<div id="page_content">
    @yield('content')
</div>
   @yield('userscript')

</body>
</html>
```

В каждом шаблоне  мне придется для отображения меню `@yield('navbar'`) прописывать секцию  меню. есть ли вариант постоянного подключения меню в этот шаблон либо какой-то вариант правильного оформления этого всего добра чтобы не прописывать секцию меню везде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то тебе нужно сделать главный шаблон, например, layout.blade.php, в котором будут подключаться необходимые для всего проекта скрипты, стили и прочее, так же как и строка меню (она, насколько я понял, должна быть "сквозная" - быть на каждой странице сайта). Это можно сделать через @include
Примерно так:

файл layout.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>...</head><body>
@include('menu')
@yield('content')
</body></html>
```

Файл menu.blade.php:

```
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Дальше создаем файлы для определенных разделов сайта, например профиль:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
  <h1>Страница профиля</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
@endsection
```

@include грубо говоря можно представить как команду "вставь вот на это место содержимое указанного файла"

@extends - примерно как "здесь находятся секции для указанного файла. Объедини нас."